# Roman to integer values

Tags: python

```
def roman_int(s):
    roman_table = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    num = 0
    last = 'I'
    for numerical in s[::-1]:
        if roman_table[numerical] < roman_table[last]:
            num -= roman_table[numerical]
        else:
            num += roman_table[numerical]
        last = numerical
    return num
s = (input('enter the roman: '))
print(roman_int(s))
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter the roman: VXI
6    (output should come as ivalid roman!)

enter the roman: VI
6
```

Above the output while run the code given input VXI is 6 and VI is 6, if I given input VXI output should come invalid roman, I dont know how to express the code to get invalid roman, Can anyone suggest me what would be change in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validation dictionary that stores which smaller number can precede the character. For e.g. the only small number than 10 (out of V and I) which can be just behind X would be I in case of 9 (IX).

```
def roman_int(s):
    roman_table = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    valid_prev = {
        'I': '',
        'V': 'I',
        'X': 'I',
        'L': 'X',
        'C': 'X',
        'D': 'C',
        'M': 'C',
    }
    num = 0
    last = ''
    for curr in s[::-1]:
        if curr not in roman_table:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Roman String')
        if last:
            if roman_table[curr] < roman_table[last]:
                if valid_prev[last] == curr:
                    num -= roman_table[curr]
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Invalid Roman String')
            else:
                num += roman_table[curr]
                last = curr
        else:
            num += roman_table[curr]
            last = curr
                
    return num

s = 'MCCXXXIV'
print(roman_int(s))
```